# Finding specific data in Oracle Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I needed to find a value for a column in my oracle database but i don't know which
table or column it's stored in

How can I search for a specific `or like %%` data as I do in

```sql
select * from SYS.dba_source
```

is there a table like that

```
Column Name ID  Data Type             Null?         Comments

OWNER   1   VARCHAR2 (30 Byte)       Y  
NAME    2   VARCHAR2 (30 Byte)       Y    Name of the object
TYPE    3   VARCHAR2 (12 Byte)       Y    

Type of the object:
"TYPE", "TYPE BODY", "PROCEDURE", "FUNCTION",
"PACKAGE", "PACKAGE BODY" or "JAVA SOURCE"

LINE    4   NUMBER                  Y    Line number of this line of source
TEXT    5   VARCHAR2 (4000 Byte)    Y    Source text
```

Comment: i faced this problem when i had a form 6i that having data and i dont have the source to know from where its getting it "table" so this is a way to solve saving me time search tables randomaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINK: **pl/sq to find any data in a schema**](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/find_in_tables.html)

**Imagine**, there are a few tables in your schema and you want to find a specific value in all columns within these tables. Ideally, there would be an sql function like

```
select * from * where any(column) = 'value';
```

Unfortunately, there is no such function.
However, a **`PL/SQL`** function can be written that does that. The following function iterates over all character columns in all tables of the current schema and tries to find val in them.

```sql
  create or replace function find_in_schema(val varchar2) 
    return varchar2 is
      v_old_table user_tab_columns.table_name%type;
      v_where     Varchar2(4000);
      v_first_col boolean := true;
      type rc     is ref cursor;
      c           rc;
      v_rowid     varchar2(20);

    begin
      for r in (
        select
          t.*
        from
          user_tab_cols t, user_all_tables a
        where t.table_name = a.table_name
          and t.data_type like '%CHAR%'
        order by t.table_name) loop

        if v_old_table is null then
          v_old_table := r.table_name;
        end if;

        if v_old_table <> r.table_name then
          v_first_col := true;

          -- dbms_output.put_line('searching ' || v_old_table);

          open c for 'select rowid from "' || v_old_table || '" ' || v_where;

          fetch c into v_rowid;
          loop
            exit when c%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line('  rowid: ' || v_rowid || ' in ' || v_old_table);
            fetch c into v_rowid;
          end loop;

          v_old_table := r.table_name;
        end if;

        if v_first_col then
          v_where := ' where ' || r.column_name || ' like ''%' || val || '%''';
          v_first_col := false;
        else
          v_where := v_where || ' or ' || r.column_name || ' like ''%' || val || '%''';
        end if;

      end loop;
      return 'Success';
    end;
```